# Replace each nth occurrence of 'foo' by numerically respective nth line of a supplied file

Tags: string, bash, replace, text-processing

I looked for a solution before posting this issue but I just found intermediate answers such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/143392/replace-nth-occurence-of-string-in-each-line-of-a-text-file) . I feel that it is very likely to have any questions exactly or similar to mine, but I have not found such a matter.

I would like to replace each nth occurrence of `foo` on the *1.txt file* by nth numerically corresponding line of a *0.txt file* containing the following content below (this is MWE).

**0.txt:**

```
The sun has its own light
    foo
The moon reflects the sunlight
    foo
The planet Earth receives both sunlight and moonlight
    foo
```

**1.txt:**

```
cat1.frog1_rain1 (('f1','b1'), ('g1','h1'))
cat2.frog2_rain2 (('f2','b2'), ('g2','h2'))
cat3.frog3_rain3 (('f3','b3'), ('g3','h3'))
```

Applying the replacement, e.g. `'command_method' 0.txt 1.txt > 2.txt` (pseudocode), I would have the desired output file is as below, being the printed output on a third *2.txt file*:

**2.txt:**

```
The sun has its own light
     cat1.frog1_rain1 (('f1','b1'), ('g1','h1'))
The moon reflects the sunlight
     cat2.frog2_rain2 (('f2','b2'), ('g2','h2'))
The planet Earth receives both sunlight and moonlight
     cat3.frog3_rain3 (('f3','b3'), ('g3','h3'))
```

Comment: Please try: `awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {gsub("foo", a[++i])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt`

Comment: @tshiono my output with `awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {gsub("foo", a[++i])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt` it has be https://imgur.com/a/6OwKC3S. What is the reason for the first occurrence of `foo` in 0.txt have been replaced by the second line of 1.txt (instead of being replaced by the second line of 1.txt)?

Comment: Hmm... I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @tshiono Here my 0.txt (https://imgur.com/a/TRSOO9B) and 1.txt (https://imgur.com/a/4fbuRV8). I also do not know how it might have worked for you `awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {gsub("foo", a[++i])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt` but have resulted in a different output for me.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Then how about: `awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /foo/{gsub("foo", a[++i])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt`

Comment: I realized that for your first solution the replacement was happening but that the increment was starting a step before `a++1` and so the first replacement was not being printed (although the replacement is happening in the background but not synchronously therefore), I was reviewing your first solution, now with the second solution may be clearer. IMHO

Comment: @tshiono `awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /foo/{gsub("foo", a[++i])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt` have work!

Comment: @tshiono I would have posted your solution as the answer so that I check the issue as settled.

Comment: All right. I'd leave it to you.

Comment: Or do you want me to post?

Comment: @tshiono Please, it would be important to keep the rules of authorship of the solution to help other users to properly understand how the solution was given. So please post yourself your own response.

Comment: Okay, I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /foo/{gsub("foo", a[++i])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt
```