# Replace each nth occurrence of 'foo' and 'bar' on two distincts columns by numerically respective nth line of a supplied file in respective columns

Tags: string, awk, replace, gsub, text-processing

I have a `source.txt` file like below containing two columns of data. The format of the columns of source.txt include `[` `]` (*square bracket*) as shown in my `source.txt`:

```
[hot] [water]
[16] [boots and, juice]
```

and I have another `target.txt` file and contain empty lines plus full stops at the end of each line:

```
the weather is today (foo) but we still have (bar). 

= (

the next bus leaves at (foo) pm, we can't forget to take the (bar).
```

I want to do replace `foo` of each nth line of `target.txt` with the "respective contents" of the *first column* of `source.txt`, and also replace `bar` of each nth line of `target.txt` with the "respective contents" of the *second column* of `source. txt`.

i tried to search other sources and understand how i would do it, at first i already have a command that i use to replace [*"replace each nth occurrence of 'foo' by numerically respective nth line of a supplied file"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66739579/10824251) but i couldn't adapt it:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /foo/{gsub("foo", a[++i])} 1' source.txt target.txt > output.txt;
```

I remember seeing a way to use gsub with containing two columns of data but I don't remember what exactly the difference was.

**EDIT POST:** sometimes read with some symbols between them `=` and `(` and `)` within the target.txt text. I added this symbol as some answers will not work if these symbols are in the `target.txt` file

Note: the number of `target.txt` lines and therefore the number of occurrences of `bar` and `foo` in this file can vary, I just showed a sample. But the number of occurrences of both `foo` and `bar` in each row is 1 respectively.

Comment: do you mean you want the nth line of source to be substituted into the nth line of target? Your example has 2 lines in source but there are three lines in target.

Comment: So you mean the expected result for the first line is *"the weather is today **hot** but we still have **water"*** and for the second *"the next bus leaves at **16** pm, we can't forget to take the **boots and, juice"***?

Comment: To do that, you just need two arrays. If the line numbers should always match up, you can use `FNR` instead of `i++`.

Comment: @tripleee exactly must: result for the first line is "the weather is today hot but we still have water" and for the second "the next bus leaves at 16 pm, we can't forget to take the boots and, juice"

Comment: Probably [edit] your question to clarify the requirements.

Comment: @jhnc I modified the formatting of the target.txt file to contain empty lines, I have other target.txt files that will have empty lines, so I'm adding this to the question.

Comment: @tripleee that's probably what I've seen with gsub, so I'll try to adapt using `FNR` instead of ` i++` .

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, could you please confirm on, is foo coming always before bar? If no then on what basis substitution should happen. Kindly clarify it more, thank you.

Comment: so is source line 2 supposed to match target line 3 now? or source line 3 (non-existent) is used for target line 3?

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, Also can there be multiple instances of foo, bar in single line? OR they are always going to be same as per line in source file?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 only one occurrence per line whether `foo` or `bar`. Also if any line of `target.txt` ends with `.`  next to `bar` is a condition that I should edit in my question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following answer. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'\\[|\\] \\[|\\]' '
FNR==NR{
  foo[FNR]=$2
  bar[FNR]=$3
  next
}
NF{
  gsub(/\<foo\>/,foo[++count])
  gsub(/\<bar\>/,bar[count])
}
1
' source.txt FS=" " target.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F'\\[|\\] \\[|\\]' '       ##Setting field separator as [ OR ] [ OR ] here.
FNR==NR{                        ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when source.txt will be read.
  foo[FNR]=$2                   ##Creating foo array with index of FNR and value of 2nd field here.   
  bar[FNR]=$3                   ##Creating bar array with index of FNR and value of 3rd field here.
  next                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
NF{                             ##If line is NOT empty then do following.
  gsub(/\<foo\>/,foo[++count])  ##Globally substituting foo with array foo value, whose index is count.
  gsub(/\<bar\>/,bar[count])    ##Globally substituting bar with array of bar with index of count.
}
1                               ##printing line here.
' source.txt FS=" " target.txt  ##Mentioning Input_files names here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding following solution also which will handle n number of occurrences of `[...]` in source and matching them at target file also. Since this is a working solution for OP(confirmed in comments) adding this in here. Also fair warning this will fail when source.txt contains a &.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){
    arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  next
}
{
  line=$0
  while(match(line,/\(?[[:space:]]*(\<foo\>|\<bar\>)[[:space:]]*\)?/)){
    val=substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    sub(val,arr[++count1])
    line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
1
' source.txt target.txt
```

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, we could continue our chat here which we left in previous comments here please.

Comment: I found it better to cover unexpected situations from the content of `target.txt`, there is an *EDIT POST*, please see.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, ok try changing `awk -F'\\[|\\] \\[|\\]'` TO `awk -F'\\[|\\] \\[|\\]|=|\\(|\\)'` once, fair warning this is not tested, this is as per your posted edit only, Let me know how it goes?

Comment: now i obtain: `the weather is today (hot) but we still have (water). = ( the next bus leaves at () pm, we can't forget to take the ().`.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, I am sorry this is getting confused now. I am not sure what input line you are using? Is it `[hot] [water]`? OR `(hot]) (water)`?

Comment: is `[hot] [water]` on the `source.txt`. I tested your previous solution. `awk ' FNR==NR{ while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){ arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/^(foo|bar)$/){ $i=arr[++count1] } } } 1 ' source.txt target.txt` and work well except if there are spaces between `(` and `foo` and `)` or between `(` and `bar` and `)` it doesn't work just delete foo and bar resulting in () in any replacement.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, ok based on your previous comment editing my working solution for you. Please try like `awk ' FNR==NR{ while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){ arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/^\(?[[:space:]]*(foo|bar)[[:space:]]*\)?$/){ $i=arr[++count1] } } } 1 ' source.txt target.txt`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry i meant work well except if **not there are spaces** between `(` and `foo` and `)` or between `(` and `bar` and `)` it doesn't work just delete `foo` and `bar` resulting in `()` in any replacement. Your solution might be marked as resolved, I'm just stumbling when this happens.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, yeah you mean when its like: `( foo` ) it doesn't work. if this is the case then please try my previous comment's answer once? should work IMHO, though its not tested, I have written on mobile, but should work IMHO, let me know.

Comment: i changed `if($i~/^(foo|bar)$/)` to `if($i~/^\(?[[:space:]]*(foo|bar)[[:space:]]*\)?$/)` but the code only works fine **when there are spaces** between `foo` or `bar` and `(` or `)`.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, it should work without spaces one also. Since I am using * with spaces.

Comment: I'm going to rescan the code and see what I'm doing wrong or if I accidentally changed the code. Here a sample of the code changed: `awk ' FNR==NR{ while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){ arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/^\(?[[:space:]]*(foo|bar)[[:space:]]*\)?$/){ $i=arr[++count1] } } } 1 ' source.txt target.txt`.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, how about using `awk 'FNR==NR{while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)};next}{line=$0;while(match(line,/^\(?[[:space:]]*(foo|bar)[[:space:]]*\)?$/)){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(val,arr[++count1]);line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)}} 1 ' source.txt target.txt` once? Let me know.

Comment: this time using `awk 'FNR==NR{while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)};next}{line=$0;while(match(line,/^\(?[[:space:]]*(foo|bar)[[:space:]]*\)?$/)){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(val,arr[++count1]);line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)}} 1 ' source.txt target.txt` no replacement was made, I tried deleting or putting `*` extras but it didn't change the result.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, please try `awk 'FNR==NR{while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)};next}{line=$0;while(match(line,/^\(?[[:space:]]*(foo|bar)[[:space:]]*\)?$/)){val=substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(val,arr[++count1]);line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)}} 1 ' source.txt target.txt` once?

Comment: I think there's something I don't notice happening, `awk 'FNR==NR{while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)};next}{line=$0;while(match(line,/^\(?[[:space:]]*(foo|bar)[[:space:]]*\)?$/)){val=substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(val,arr[++count1]);line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)}} 1 ' source.txt target.txt` not work also. I marked your answer as resolved but I can't really get result when there are no spaces between `(` `)` and `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: That will fail when source.txt contains a `&`. It'd also replace `foo` in other contexts than just `(foo)`.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, Sorry I have fixed it now, please try `awk 'FNR==NR{while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)};next}{line=$0;while(match(line,/\(?[[:space:]]*(\<foo\>|\<bar\>)[[:space:]]*\)?/)){val=substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(val,arr[++count1]);line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)}} 1 ' source.txt target.txt` once?

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks sir, I have used boundaries in regex now. For containing & I will add a warning here once OP confirms that my previous comment's version is working.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 `awk 'FNR==NR{while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/)){arr[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)};next}{line=$0;while(match(line,/\(?[[:space:]]*(\<foo\>|\<bar\>)[[:space:]]*\)?/)){val=substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(val,arr[++count1]);line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)}} 1 ' source.txt target.txt`  resolved all interactions with symbols including spacing, resolved.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  boundaries aren't the problem (in fact you specifically do NOT need boundaries in this case) - matching `foo` whether it's within parens or not and using a *sub() replacement are the problems. If OP thinks it works then they just haven't hit those cases in their data yet. Try it when source.txt contains `[hot] [fire & water]` and target.txt contains `this foo is (foo) and (bar)`.

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk in any shell on  every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[][]"
    tags["foo"]
    tags["bar"]
}
NR==FNR {
    map["foo",NR] = $2
    map["bar",NR] = $4
    next
}
{
    found = 0
    head = ""
    while ( match($0,/\([^)]+)/) ) {
        tag = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        if ( tag in tags ) {
            if ( !found++ ) {
                lineNr++
            }
            val = map[tag,lineNr]
        }
        else {
            val = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        }
        head = head substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk source.txt target.txt
the weather is today hot but we still have water.

= (

the next bus leaves at 16 pm, we can't forget to take the boots and, juice.
```

Comment: i have been saving the output of `tst.awk` in a `tst.awk` file and doing `awk -f tst.awk source.txt target.txt` but it hasn't produced any output as expected, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had made one final tweak and hadn't noticed that had broken the script and it wasn't producing the expected output and dismissed your comment out of hand. I fixed that now.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { # build lookup

        # delete gumph
        gsub(/(^[[:space:]]*\[)|(\][[:space:]]*$)/, "")

        # split
        split($0, a, /\][[:space:]]+\[/)

        # store
        foo[FNR] = a[1]
        bar[FNR] = a[2]

        next
    }

    !/[^[:space:]]/ { next } # ignore blank lines

    { # do replacements
        VFNR++ # FNR - (ignored lines)

        # can use sub if foo/bar only appear once
        gsub(/\<foo\>/, foo[VFNR])
        gsub(/\<bar\>/, bar[VFNR])

        print
    }
' source.txt target.txt
```

Note: `\<` and `\>` are not in POSIX but are accepted by some versions of awk (eg. gawk). I'm not sure if POSIX awk regex has "word boundary".

Comment: at the outuput print the first line has been `.he weather is today hot but we still have water]`

Comment: the problem is that I always get `water]` at the end of the output print line, even in this last edit of your answer.

Comment: my awk version is "GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)" on the OS Arch Linux.

Comment: Does your source.txt have whitespace after the `water]` ?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, in `source.txt` there is no white space after `water]` just the line break to the second line like in my post.

Comment: your last edit fixed what was happening with `water]`, now this ok!

Comment: I needed to change my post see *EDIT POST*, sorry and thanks.