# Replace each nth occurrence of 'foo' and 'bar' by numerically respective nth line of a supplied file once time

Tags: awk, command-line, gsub, find-occurrences

I would like to use a single command line (I tried to do this with pipe and process substitution but unsuccessfully as explained below) to replace each nth occurrence of `home_cool` and `home_cool01`) by numerically respective nth line of a supplied file, preferably not using pipe but adding `home_cool01` as another pattern fetched in the command.

Knowing that `0.txt` contains *2 occurrences* of `home_cool` and *2 occurrences* of `home_cool01`.

I have this commands (*used in sequence*) that replace each nth occurrence of `home_cool` and `home_cool01` by numerically respective nth line of a supplied file `1.txt` bellow:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /home_cool/{gsub("home_cool", a[++i])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt
```

and

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /home_cool01/{gsub("home_cool01", a[++i])} 1' 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt
```

but i don't want two separate commands even if using `pipe`.

Here my files:

file `0.txt` bellow:

```
"#sun\t",
"\t",
"bread = door('dog', 'paint')\t",
"door = world.sea\t",
"world.sea = bread\t",
"\t",
"machine(\"home_cool\")\t",
"\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",

"machine(car_snif.car_snif)\t",
"door = world.sea\t",
"world.sea = bread\t",
"\t",
"machine(\"home_cool01\")\t",
"\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"machine(car_snif.car_snif)\t",
```

flle 1.txt bellow:

```
(food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,)
(food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,)
(food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, moon, tortoise,)
```

my desired result is 2.txt bellow:

```
  "#sun\t",
    "\t",
    "bread = door('dog', 'paint')\t",
    "door = world.sea\t",
    "world.sea = bread\t",
    "\t",
    "machine(\"(food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,)\")\t",
    "\t",
    "car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
    "\t",
    "machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
    "machine(car_snif.car_snif)\t",
    "door = world.sea\t",
    "world.sea = bread\t",
    "\t",
    "machine(\"(food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,)\")\t",
    "\t",
    "car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
    "\t",
    "machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
    "machine(car_snif.car_snif)\t",
```

**Note:** I could consider this question as a sub-question of [Replace each nth occurrence of 'foo' by numerically respective nth line of a supplied file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738909/replace-each-nth-occurrence-of-foo-by-numerically-respective-nth-line-of-a-sup)
and I thought about asking via chat or comments to help the authors of this subquestion, but I believe this is a new question to be done, so I opened a new post here on the OS.

Comment: If you can reduce this to a [mcve] (1 small script, 1 small sample input file, the associated expected output, no scroll bars, and a concise statement of what you're trying to do and the problem you're asking for help with) then a lot more people will have the time to invest reading your question to try to help you.

Comment: @EdMorton I will decrease the number of occurrences of the pattern to 2 instead of 4.

Comment: If the end result is your question still contains 5 awk scripts and sample input with a scroll bar then that won't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next}
    /home_cool01/ {gsub("home_cool01", a[++i])}
    /home_cool/ {gsub("home_cool", a[++j])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt
```

- I split the command in three lines just for readability but you can
  combine them in one line.
- The two variables `i` and `j` work individually for each numerical
  referencing.
- The matching with `home_cool01` needs to be tested first, otherwise
  `home_cool` will match the substring of `home_cool01`.